# How can I have an item in a list correspond to an object?

Tags: python, list

I've been working on a project that utilizes PyQt. In this project, we are processing some changes to "Modules" (as we call them). Some of those changes are forwarded to a list in a parent class. The most important part is that those changes stick with the item in that list.

[image: 36568444-47afedf0-17e7-11e8-8ae9-775cadd54d66]

Below is a small example of some code that has been worked to fit into what it is I'm trying to do.

```
class Module:
    some_list = []

    def setList(self, _list, _item):
        try:
            _list[_list.index(_item)] = _item
        except:
            _list.append(_item)


class someUI(Module):
    index = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setList(self, _list, _item):
        super().setList(_list, _item)


f = someUI()
g = someUI()
f.setList(f.some_list, 'item1')
g.setList(g.some_list, 'item2')
```

As you can see I've added a list `some_list`, this list is accessible to any classes that extend the `Module` class. 
The expected result should be that every time we add new Modules (given by `f` and `g`) their corresponding space in `some_list` should be remembered.

In other words, when a new 'module' is added a new space should be added to `some_list`. Whenever that 'module' is edited we want only the corresponding item in `some_list` to change. 
For example: If I'm messing with `f` then the corresponding location `some_list[0]` should be the only place things change. If I'm messing with `g` then the corresponding location `some_list[1]` should be the only place things change. If however nothing exists in `some_list[0]` then we will want to create it.  As you can see `setList` is an attempt at doing this.

This should remain consistent as we add new items and classes. Basically, we want the index of `some_list` and the instantiation of each new object to be tied together.

```
class anotherUI(Module):
     ...

h = anotherUI()
h.setList(h.some_list, 'item3')
```

---

After messing around a little more, I've found that I can use a dictionary to do what I'm asking.

```
class Module:
    some_list = {}

    def setItem(self, name, item):
        self.some_list[name] = item


class someUI(Module):
    index = -1

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        someUI.index += 1
        self.curr_count = someUI.index

    def setItem(self, _item, **kwargs):
        super().setItem(self.curr_count, _item)


f = someUI()
g = someUI()
f.setItem('item1')
g.setItem('item2')
f.setItem('item3')
```

---

```
Output: 
{0: 'item3', 1: 'item2'}
```

However, a new problem has arisen. How can I add a new class, and have it recognize that it shouldn't overwrite items in the dictionary?

```
class anotherUI(Module):
     ...

h = anotherUI()
h.setList('item3')

Output
{0: 'item3', 1: 'item2', 2: 'item3'}
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far and why doesn't it work?

Comment: I would suggest you first need to go through this [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank @Reck, I do understand MCV, that is why I tried to design the code example as small as possible. The current implementation running in my program is big. Thus, this example is as minimal as possible, that still has an output. Please let me know what it is that is confusing you in terms of my code implementation.